# Elegant way to match and replace part of string

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data tables like namely dt and dt1

```
dt <- data.table(s=c("AA-AA-1", "BB-BB-2", "CC-CC-3"))
        s
1 AA-AA-1
2 BB-BB-2
3 CC-CC-3

dt1 <- data.table(x=c(1,2,3), name=c("AA", "BB", "CC"))
   x   name
1: 1   AA
2: 2   BB
3: 3   CC
```

I need to replace part of string in s column of dt  with name column of dt1 by matching number after last hyphen of s & x col in dt1 column in dt, so that dt becomes like this.

```
      s
1: AA-AA-AA
2: BB-BB-BB
3: CC-CC-CC
```

I know  we can do it by splitting s and matching

```
split <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(dt$s), split="-"), tail, n=1)
dt1$name[match(dt$split, dt1$x)
```

Is there any way to speed it up in elegant way?

Comment: As you are asking for speeding up the code, how many rows do `dt` and `dt1` have, resp., in your production setting?

Comment: The rows in dt could reach upto a million and has It has lots columns. Its repeated operation so I need to save whatever time I could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a slightly more general approach.

```
mapply(function(pat, repl, src){ sub(pat, repl, src) }, pat = dt1$x, repl = dt1$name, src = dt$s )

#[1] "AA-AA-AA" "BB-BB-BB" "CC-CC-CC"
```

If you say you always want to replace **after last - (hyphen)**, then you can simplify as:

```
mapply(function(repl, src){ sub("(?<=-)[^-]+$", repl, src, perl = T) }, repl = dt1$name, src = dt$s )
```

---

Please note: My solution works only if `dt` and `dt1` are ordered like in the example. This means each first rows are related, ... and so on. If this is not the case consider a combination of @Tims (the merging ...) and my solution.

---

So here is a rock-solid solution using some of Tim's ideas:

```
dt  <- data.table(s=c("AA-AA-1", "BB-BB-2", "CC-CC-3"))
dt1 <- data.table(x=3:1, name=c("CC", "BB", "AA"))  # note the order is not right.

dt$x <- sub(".*-", "", dt$s)
dt   <- merge.default(dt, dt1, by="x")
dt$endResult <- mapply(function(repl, src){ sub("(?<=-)[^-]+$", repl, src, perl = T) }, repl = dt$name, src = dt$s )
```

Comment: my dt and dt1 may not be in order. your solution looks good it doest not introduce new column in dt table. I need that. can you please look into it likewise.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base R approach.  We can create an `x` column in the first `dt` data table, using the digit appearing to the right of the final dash.  Then, we can `merge` the two data tables on `x`, and finally concatenate the `s` result you expect.

```
dt$x <- sub(".*-", "", dt$s)
result <- merge(dt, dt1, by="x")
result$s <- paste0(sub("\\d+", "", result$s), result$name)

result$s
[1] "AA-AA-AA" "BB-BB-BB" "CC-CC-CC"
```

### Demo

Answer (score 3):

### base R, sprintf + sub

```
mapply(sprintf, sub("[^-]+$", "%s", dt$s), dt1$name) 
#   AA-AA-%s   BB-BB-%s   CC-CC-%s 
# "AA-AA-AA" "BB-BB-BB" "CC-CC-CC"
```

I presumed that both data frames are in a matching order (as they are in the example). If not, you need to match them before, for example:

```
mapply(sprintf, sub("-.?$", "-%s", dt$s), dt1$name[match(gsub("[^0-9]","", dt$s), dt1$x)])
```

Comment: I like the idea, but OP is pretty explicit about matching `x` to the number

Comment: @eddi thanks for the edit. I added a line that does matching before `sprintf`ing ..

Answer (score 3):

I'd take the straightforward approach:

```
dt1[dt[, .(x = as.integer(sub('.*-', '', s)), str = sub('[^-]+$', '', s))],
    on = .(x), .(s = paste0(str, name))]
#          s
#1: AA-AA-AA
#2: BB-BB-BB
#3: CC-CC-CC
```

Answer (score -1):

If they are sorted appropriately as in your example you can use `stringr::str_replace`:

```
library(stringr)
dt[,s := str_replace(s,as.character(dt1$x),dt1$name)]
dt
#           s
# 1: AA-AA-AA
# 2: BB-BB-BB
# 3: CC-CC-CC
```